# How can I display a custom key popup on a keyboard accessory view?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uikeyboard

I want to present an option to select from several keys after a long press, the way that a regular keyboard does for accent characters. I want to make it look and act like the keyboard, instead of implementing it with the big black-bordered popover.